# Assign selected item of a dropdown list of jsp file to a java variable (say String selection)

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I want to display the table data from database according to the selected item from a dropdown list in my jsp file, so all I need to do is assign that selected value to a variable of String type, how do i do that, suggest me the piece of code along with the code of dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a dropdown element in your form of your JSP page as below:

```
<select name='ele1'>
  <option value='a'>A</option>
  <option value='b'>B</option>
  ...
</select>
```

After submitting the form, you can get the element value from HttpServletRequest:

```
String selectedValue = request.getParameter("ele1");
```

Comment: I want to do it before submitting.. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: As far as I know, that's not doable...Maybe you can try DWR, the library will implement the underlying thing to make it look like the value is "automatically synchronized" to server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax, check out the link http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=580